# How can I get the Geronimo achievement in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

I noticed this achievement in the Challenger: Series II

[image: Geronimo! Hit an opponent with a Plunging Attack after plunging for more than 5 seconds.]

I have tried from the top of the Dragonspine needle, but I can't see the enemies to land correctly. Or I plunge so far the character just dies on impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a monster on the ground near the base of Mt. Aozang and mark them on your map:

[image: Screenshot of the map.]

Teleport to the top of Qingyun peak and jump in the direction of your marker.

[image: Screenshot of the jump.]

Be sure to check your map before you plunge to ensure you're over the monster's location, then of course, plunge:

[image: Screenshot of the attack.]

---

Here is the video tutorial that fueled this answer:

Comment: Cooler version would be falling straight on the hilichurl archer near the Falcon beach.... from atop the floating platform that was only available during a limited event.